# How can I open a webpage in LWJGL/Java?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I would like to open a webpage when a person clicks something.

For example, user clicks "go to webpage" in my start screen, and internet explorer (Or your default browser) is opened and goes directly to a domain that I specify.

I am using LWJGL and Java, however if I need to use a library I do not see a large problem with that.

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: LWJGL is irrelevant to this question (and its answer)

Comment: @Darkhogg It's not irrelevant especially if you don't want to rely on AWT, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through one of the AWT methods:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(/* insert url here */);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Just a quick question, why is it URI and not URL? What is URI?

Comment: Typo, it should be a string representing your URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with LWJGL 2:
[org.lwjgl.openURL(String url)](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/Sys.html#openURL%28java.lang.String%29)

I haven't found any equivalent method in LWJGL 3.